# Overloading in a Mackie profx8

Tags: mixer

On one channel of my Mackie mixer, the OL light is on whatever I do. The channel sounds like it's working but the OL light is lit. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning the gain all the way down and unplugging the channel.  If the overload light is still lit, then there is a fault with your board.

Comment: Ok. I will take it with the store where I bought it. The channel sounds OK, it might be a glitch with the light itself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe u mistakenly press button solo

Comment: I forgot those boards do this.  That's a great thought.